# How can I access a container on boot2docker through the web browser?

Tags: macos, docker, ip, boot2docker

I've used docker successfully on my Ubuntu laptop, but my coworker has boot2docker on his Macbook Air and is trying to set up a container that we both need to work on.

On the boot2docker VM I have 2 port forwards, 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 172...:80 and 127.0.0.1:13306 -> 172...:3306 where 172... is the container's IP on the boot2docker VM. I also used the `-p` flag when I ran the docker image (inside boot2docker) respectively `8080:80` and `13306:3306`.

At this point I assume all I need is the IP of the boot2docker VM to access it on port 8080, but I can't find it anywhere.

So do I just need to access the boot2docker VM on its IP and port 8080 and I'll be done? If so, how do I find the boot2docker's IP?

Or do I need to try another approach at this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you need to determine the IP address of the boot2docker container:

```
boot2docker ip
```

> ```
> The VM's Host only interface IP address is: <X.X.X.X>
> ```

You should then be able to access `<X.X.X.X>:8080`

Comment: Should this be run on the Mac's shell or the VM's shell?

Comment: Run this command on your Mac's shell. boot2docker has been depricated and now it has been replaced by docker-machine. You can read more about it at the docker's website.